# Django 1.7 how to access values after annotate

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I am using Django 1.7 and am trying to do an aggregation query.  They query seems to work until I iterate through the ValueSet.

```
>> messages = Message.objects.filter(is_outgoing=False)
              .values('contact_id').annotate(Max('created')
>> messages.count()
5
```

This is correct.  There are only 5 unique contacts.

However, once I do this:

```
for m in messages:
    do stuff here
```

Now when I do messages.count()  I get 49 which is the total number of messages not grouped by client.

How can I iterate through the ValueSet and only get the 5 most recent messages?

Edit:

I found out what was happening.  I had Meta.ordering set to '-created' in Message class.  These means that the ORM was adding a group by on created so the query being generated was grouping by both 'created' and 'contact_id'.

I added a order_by() before the annotate() to remove the default ordering and it fixed the problem.

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(is_outgoing=False)
           .values('contact_id').order_by().annotate(Max('created'))
```

Comment: And when I do iterate through the ValueSet it iterates through all 49 messages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you alter `messages` in the "do stuff here" code or after the first iteration.